# Reading query-string in asp.net without specifying any page name

Tags: asp.net, query-string

How to read any strings in a aspx page.

example: http://foo.com/bike stand

I want to read/get the strings in a specified aspx page.
expected page string is **bike stand**
expected page is **getstring.aspx**

Here i like to read the string and redirect to specified page.
**Note:** I like to do this in just ASP.Net  (Not with MVC)

Comment: Do you want to get the query string parameters and redirect to that page based on the parameter?

Comment: Expected page is always `getstring.aspx`?

Comment: Yes AliBaig. based on query string i like to redirect the same to another page.  and getstring.aspx is just an example page name can be changed.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably solve this using a `Route`. I have made a simple demo, that you can try out in just a couple of minutes. In the `Global.asax.cs` file, add this method:

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("Products",
        "Products/{product}", "~/getstring.aspx",
        false,
        new RouteValueDictionary { { "product", "NoneSelected" } }
    );
}
```

In the same file, in the already existing `void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)` method, add `RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);`:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

With this, you have configured a `Route` which will take a request like this:

```
http://foo.com/Products/bike%20stand
```

and map it to `getstring.aspx`. Note that I have url encoded the space in the url.

In `getstring.aspx` you can access the value ("bike stand") like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string routeValue = "";
    if (RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("product"))
        routeValue = RouteData.Values["product"].ToString();

    //routeValue now contains "bike stand"

    SelectedProduct.Text = routeValue;
}
```

I have set up the `Route` in this sample on the path "Products" beneath the application folder. I don't recommend that you setup your route directly under the application folder as in the question. You *can* do it though if you absolutely want to:

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("Products",
        "{product}", "~/getstring.aspx",
        false,
        new RouteValueDictionary { { "product", "NoneSelected" } }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It may not the best way to fulfill your need but if you want to get the string part from URL you may use URI Segments.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments.Select(x=>x.TrimEnd‌​('/')).Skip(2).ToArr‌​ay();
```

OR

```
new Uri("http://www.someurl.com/foo/xyz/index.htm#extra_text").Segments
```

Results: `[ "/", "foo/", "xyz/", "index.html" ]`

After reading string you can do whatever you want  like redirection etc

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [IIS URL Rewrite Module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) for this. When installed you can create a rule in the Web.Config `System.Webserver` node that rewrites the url so the string can be processed in code behind as a QueryString.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="getString" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([a-z0-9- /]+)$" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="getstring.aspx?string={R:1}"/>
    </rule>      
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Then you can simply get the string value with this:

```
string getString = Request.QueryString["string"];
```

But his will create a problem if there are other pages than `getstring.aspx` than need to be accessed since every request is now being send to getstring.aspx. Maybe it's better to use a prefix so that you can identify the request URL as being one that has a string.

```
http://foo.com/getstring/bike stand

<match url="^getstring/([a-z0-9- /]+)$" ignoreCase="true"/>
```